# How to close SFSafariViewController automatically?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to close `SFSafariViewController` without user need to tap on the Done button on the top left corner.

```
let svc = SFSafariViewController(URL: NSURL(string: "http://spotify.com")!)

self.presentViewController(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: you want to detect when user thinks "I want to close it"? )))

Comment: yea any built in function can do that?

Comment: sure. userDidThink(userThoughts : String). You need to import MindKit ))))

Comment: Sarcasm Translator: If there is no user input, what will determine when it closes?

Comment: Authentication. In Android after having given permission to an app to login in a site with our credential, the view with the login web page automatically closes. I don't see why I have to press a button either. It served me my stuff, it can go away.

Answer (score 2):

I add this solution here , because i was looking for same behaviour and i didn't find any good answer.

Present your SFSafariViewController like that:

```
    let URL = NSURL(string: "www.to-load.com")
    let webVC = SFSafariViewController(url: URL! as URL)
    present(webVC, animated: true)
    webVC.loadViewIfNeeded()
```

and then you can close it like that.

```
   self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
   self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Yes, i did check that , it works.

Comment: Do you have any solution for SwiftUI. I am stuck in similar problem